# Graphic representation of averages

Tags: sampling, data-visualization, boxplot, tables, types-of-averages

I have a series of averages. One of these however turns out to take too high a value due to a N. low equal to 1.

Let me explain better by means of an example: I have to calculate the averages of the fishing days for each month for a sample n. of fishermen. Now in May it appears that only 1 fisherman went fishing.

Therefore, compared to the other months, the data is very different only because in that month there is only 1 respondent. Representing this data on a boxplot could lead to misunderstandings.

-What to do in these cases?
-Enter the data or not?
-Insert a table (legend) with the number of "respondents" (fishermen) by choosing a minimum number of data is reported with an asterisk?
-Is there anything in literature that could help me?

Comment: Maybe instead of a boxplot you can try a stripplot.

Comment: Many people draw some form of "error bars" to represent the uncertainty.  It is useful to know that the standard error of a count of independent events can be estimated by the square root of that count.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that a boxplot would be bad, because a boxplot would implicitly show that there was only 1 data point for May.  Could you provide a sample dataset (real, or made up) for people to work with?  More generally, who will be the audience for this plot, & what do you want them to learn from it?